# Solidity Ide- writing a smart contract, Parser Error: Expected Primary Expression. - Function withdraw

Tags: parsing, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

contract FeeCollector {//**hidden keys**

```
address public owner;
uint256 public balance;

constructor () {
    owner = msg.sender;
    }

receive () payable external {
    balance += msg.value; }


function withdraw (uint amount, address payable destAddr) { public
    require(msg.sender ==owner, "only owner can withrdaw");
    destAddr.transfer(amount);
    balance -= amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well just add `}` in the end. The rest of the code is working.
[image: Solution]

Comment: I still get the same parser error on line 16 "function withdraw)

Comment: what type of error are you facing?

Comment: Parser Error: Expected primary expression

Comment: address public owner;
uint256 public balance;
    
    constructor () {
        owner = msg.sender;
        }

    receive () payable external {
        balance += msg.value; }

function withdraw (uint amount, address payable destAddr) { public
        require(msg.sender ==owner, "only owner can withrdaw");
        destAddr.transfer(amount);
        balance -= amount; 
}  
}

Comment: Solved! 
    function withdraw (uint amount, address payable destAddr) public {
        
        destAddr.transfer(amount);
        balance -= amount; 
        }
}